# Google Chrome - Asynchronous loading of elements?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Firefox Im having no issues but in Chrome, SOMETIMES, I get an error where the onMenu part of the following is being activated before the elements are loaded:

```
self.menus[l].innerHTML = html;
self.container.appendChild(self.menus[l]);

self.onMenu.forEach(function(func){<--this is sometimes running before appendChild has loaded, causing an error. Would Chrome be caching this 'state'
    func.call(self.menus[l],self);
});

self.pagination.current++;

self.enable();
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Is the __private.minutesScroll part of the DOM?

Comment: Yes I will see if I can replicate the issue. __private.minutesScroll IS an element in the DOM. It is selected with querySelector.

Comment: Ugh I cant replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/e8wunkj0/ Im going to try using an inline style, as Im wondering if it has something to do with load speed on css even though the functions is occurring after 'complete' is called

Comment: __private.minutesScroll is loaded via a template/ajax. Im guessing that it is  not fully loaded into the DOM before the child elements are being added.